# Getting The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I am trying to deploy my Laravel app on EC2.
It works fine on local host but when copied the files to var/www/html I always get:   **The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

URL of the instance: http://ec2-52-88-99-75.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

I am assuming that I am missing something with the httpd.conf, but I am not sure what.

Here is the httpd.conf file:
   http://collabedit.com/g249v

[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Could you post the project structure, maybe a pic, also as in the httpd.conf file your pointing the server to `/var/www/html/server/public` is **server** the name of your project?

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: @JonathanS, thanks for assisting. 
it is the name of the project. attached the structure

Comment: not sure about the distro.... how can i check it?

Comment: Run this command in the terminal: `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: @JonathanS. Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09
Kernel \r on an \m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91309/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-gil404).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the checklist-

1) Check your security group port 80 should be allowed for incoming traffic.

2) Check if your public ip is still same as before on amazon ec2, its much better if you use elastic ip.

3) Check error logs of apache, incase if ther is any error related to missing php module or any other error you can quickly find and correct.

I had hosted many Laravel application on amazon Ec2 and haven't got a single issue.